# Problem in adding string value to registry with .reg file

Tags: windows, registry

I'm on win2k3 machine. I wrote a .reg file as below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\KalleService\Parameters]
"Application"="C:\Projects\KalleService\Bin\KalleService.exe"
```

When double click the .reg file/say merge, it says registry modified successfully. But it has just created the `Parameters` key and has not created `Application` string value.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\KalleService\Parameters]
"Application"="C:\\Projects\\KalleService\\Bin\\KalleService.exe"
```

try double slashes(`\\`) instead of single slash (`\`) in the string value.

Comment: Thanx. Meanwhile, I too discoverd the same thing.

Comment: @Sarfraz `@="C:\\Users\\.....test.ps1" "%1"` does not work (data field is empty), any idea why?

Comment: @JinSnow You need to escape not only `backslash` character but also inner `"` too! Like this: `@="\"C:\\Users\\...text.ps1\" \"%1\""`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\KalleService\Parameters]
@=" "
"Application"="\"C:\\Projects\\KalleService\\Bin\\KalleService.exe\""
```

or if this doesn't work
make a key manually with a value and export it (a .reg file will be created)

open that file in notepad , modify that file with your values and then again save it. and then run it.
Second way is not efficient but it will get your work done later if you do this